# not all arguments converted during string formatting for select

Tags: python, mysql

I can not select the database I have this error:

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

My script is:

```
bo=str(mac)
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM DEVICES WHERE MAC= %s """,bo)
```

Comment: can you provide more context? What is mac? Does it successfully convert to a string?

Comment: yes mac it successfully convert to a string the pb is in the sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to add % in front of bo, like this:

```
bo=str(mac)
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM DEVICES WHERE MAC= %s """, %bo)
```

Comment: it is error to put in python , %bo SyntaxError: invalid syntax